# ismember for NaN and values not working with different sized array matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

I'm trying to compare 2 different sized arrays and get the column of the matching pairs.

If I do:

```
ismembernan = @(a,b) ismember(a,b) | (isnan(a) & any(isnan(b)));
a = [NaN 11 12 13 14 15; NaN 0 1 2 3 4; NaN 5 6 7 8 9];
b = [NaN 0 1 2 3 4; NaN 5 6 7 8 9]];
k = ismembernan(a,b);
col = all(k,2);
column = find(col)
```

In MATLAB 2016b I get the expected answer

> column= 
>   2 
>   3

but in MATLAB 2014a (I have to work with this version) I get the following error:

> Error using  &
>
> Inputs must have the same size.
>
> Error in @(a,b)ismember(a,b)|(isnan(a)&any(isnan(b)))

maybe the solution is a nested for loop with an `if` statement but I'm looking for a better solution.

How can I get `ismember` to work with `nan` values in R2014a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit expansion is introduced in R2016b. In older versions, use `bsxfun` i.e.

```
ismembernan = @(a,b) ismember(a,b) | bsxfun(@and,isnan(a), any(isnan(b)));
```

Comment: Background on implicit expansion for the curious reader: [introductory MathWorks blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/).